# Install issues for SimpleNote with HomeBrew—why Intel only?

Tags: install, homebrew, mac-mini

I use SimpleNote daily across three devices and just bought an M2 MacMini.

I used `brew install --cask simplenote` to get the latest version (2.21.0) but it’s intel-only, so on opening it’s asking to install Rosetta to open… Visual Studio Code?

However, the Silicon version of VSCode is happily installed with Homebrew and working fine, so that’s not an issue. I’m guessing—since SimpleNote Intel uses React and runs on Electron like VSCode, that this is a side-issue related to Electron.

I do not want to run Rosetta, and other apps are working fine after installing the ARM versions. Is it possible to get the ARM/Silicon version of SimpleNote through a HomeBrew Cask install?

I’m on an M2 MacMini running Ventura 13.6.5.

Comment: Why use `brew`, you can get it from the MAS.

Comment: I always use Homebrew for installs and clean uninstalls. If the brew cask version doesn't get updated I’ll have to to that. Filed an issue: https://github.com/Automattic/simplenote-macos/issues/1138

Comment: Automattic closed your issue.  This is purely a Homebrew problem.

Comment: It’s not a Homebrew issue per se but a conscious decision by developers, but happy to have the issue closed. For anyone reading this, please see the exchange on GitHub for clarity: https://github.com/Automattic/simplenote-macos/issues/1138

Comment: The Mac-native version is [here](https://github.com/Automattic/simplenote-macos/releases).  Homebrew can download that, same as they download the Electron version.  They choose not to.